# Install Libraris to Heorku

Tags: heroku, unicode, libraries

I have created a userbot to translate one channel to another channel.  So I want to add this python file to Heoroku.

How can I install the googletrans, unidecode, pyrogram and tgcrypto libraries for a Heroku account?

Answer (score 0):

In the main directory add the following files :

> requirements.txt

The above file should contain all third party modules u need

> runtime.txt

```
python-3.8.3
```

> Procfile

```
worker: python3 main.py
```

Comment: I created Procile as a `web: python3 main.py.`. What is the difference between that?

Comment: @NimsaraGcu Procfiles  is used to declare the command for running your application.If ur using a webhook or webapplication project u can use web: else we use worker: [refer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-a-procfile)